# Fetch latest n records in reverse with backfilling and without duplicates

Tags: sql, database, pagination

My app shows the 10 latest records, and works similarly to email clients:

- it shows the latest 10 records
- at the bottom of the list there's a "load more" button; it loads the next (i.e. older) 10 records

In pseudocode this is what my client asks the server:

- order by reverse PK (or date)
- skip 10
- take 10

But that doesn't work. Let's say the user is also using the system via the app on his phone, and he adds 2 records from there. So the desktop app believes it has the latest 10 records, and that the table on the server looks like this:

```
1 2 3...31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40            # app has 31..40
```

But the table actually looks like this:

```
1 2 3...31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
```

So if the client skips/takes 10, it won't get `21..30` as expected, but rather `23..32`, thus:

- it won't get the latest 2 records `41 42`
- it will get 2 duplicate records `31 32`

Ideally, the client should fetch these records:
`23..30` AND `41..42`. *I could do that with multiple queries, but I want to avoid that, if possible.*

Without getting bogged down in SQL (because I'd need to translate it for my ORM (EF) anyway), I'm interested in the underlying logic to solving this problem. *Put differently, I'm not struggling with the SQL, but rather with how to think about this problem in principle, in pseudocode.* How do I approach this?

Comment: client can send smallest id it has, so server can send ids which are smaller, thus ignoring new added ones

Comment: @IłyaBursov Thanks Ilya. The problem is I also want the newest ones. Does that mean I must do two queries?

Comment: depends on how you want to display them? do you want them after currently displayed ones? or maybe you want to refresh whole screen in that case?

Comment: @IłyaBursov Yes my client app will display them in the proper order (it will put the new ones one top, and the older ones at the bottom). That is the easy part. The hard part is I don't know how best to ask for the data. I am thinking I need to make two queries, but I'm not a SQL expert, so I'm sure there is a normal way to do this, and I just don't know what it is. :-)

Comment: loading something on top could confuse user (he is looking at the bottom, so something loaded on top probably will be hidden and not noticed), anyway - just send ids of records you currently have on client to server and add `not in` condition on server thus you will send latest non duplicated ones

Comment: @IłyaBursov Aaaaah that is interesting idea. So you are saying to ignore completely the new ones (it's his fault he uses system on two devices!) and only show the older ones. The only way he can see the new ones is to refresh the webpage? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: yes, user expects that only "older" ones are loaded at the bottom, so I'd just ignore newer ones, or have separate channel to notify user and propose to reload newer only on top with auto scroll to the top

Comment: @IłyaBursov Thanks Ilya that makes a lot of sense. It makes the problem seem much smaller now... I will rethink it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have read IDs 31 to 40, and you remember these IDs. Then IDs 41 and 42 got added, and you want to select IDs 42, 41, 30 .. 23. These are the highest IDs found outside the selected range. So, just select everything outside the already selected range, order by ID in descending order and fetch 10 rows.

You don't want the SQL. Here it is anyway :-)

```
select *
from mytable
where id > :id_newest or id < :id_oldest
order by id desc
fetch first 10 rows only;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with two queries:

- client determines its

  - oldest PK = `id_oldest`
  - newest PK = `id_newest`
- issue query 1 to server, to get newest records:

  - `order by PK`
  - `where id > id_newest`
  - `take 10`
- issue query 2 to server, to get "next oldest" page:

  - `order by reverse PK`
  - `where id < id_oldest`
  - `take 10 - count(query1)`
- the two queries would return a maximum of 10 records in total

The client must then add the newest to the top of the list, add the oldest to the bottom.

(If there are many new records on the server, not all would be fetched; so another request, or more, may be needed.)

I'm not marking this as the solution, as it's hacky. I hope there's a better way with one query.